# How do I fix "no setup signature found" error on install

Tags: installation, grub2

I'm using the NetBootInstallfromInternet procedure:
 [Installation/NetbootInstallFromInternet](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/NetbootInstallFromInternet)

Using `linux` and `initrd.gz` files in my `/boot/newinstall` directory. It seems to find them OK, but get "No Setup Signature Found" message from GRUB.

I'm using Grub 0.91.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a UEFI system? If yes, then you will need to disable the Secure Boot Option from the BIOS.
A link similar to yours -

[no setup signature found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223092/no-setup-signature-found)

Another link-

[from linuxmint forums](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=35503)

Couldnt find much on the net about it.
**Try upgrading to Grub 0.97** , it solved the problem for the person who posted earlier.(in the linux mint forums); or you could upgrade to Grub 2 also.